# SQL plus query returns duplicate rows

Tags: oracle, duplicates, sqlplus

My Oracle9i query is generating duplicate rows no matter what I do. It's also incorrectly assigning values and sample numbers to dates. I've tried to use joins unsuccessfully and have had no luck using distinct either. I've also tried to type in sd.SAMPLE_NUM=shv.SAMPLE_NUM in the where statement. This has not helped me though. When I do this I get zero rows returned. Thank you in advance for any help.

```
SELECT 
         DISTINCT 
         DATE_SAMPLE,
         SW_NAME,
         SAMPLE_NUM,
         BU_ID,
         sum(case when ANALYSIS_NAME = 'METHANE-MOL%' then ANALYSIS_RESULT else null end) C1,
         sum(case when ANALYSIS_NAME = 'ETHANE-MOL%' then ANALYSIS_RESULT else null end) C2,
         sum(case when ANALYSIS_NAME = 'PROPANE-MOL%' then ANALYSIS_RESULT else null end) C3
FROM
       (
        SELECT 
                 DISTINCT 
                 sd.SW_NAME,
                 sd.SAMPLE_NUM, 
                 sd.ANALYSIS_RESULT,
                 sd.ANALYSIS_NAME,
                 sd.BU_ID,
                 shv.DATE_SAMPLE 
        FROM 
                 public_project.Sample_Data_Pbu_Lab_Vew sd,
                 public_project.Sample_Header_Vew shv
        WHERE 
                 (sd.SW_NAME LIKE '02-40%') AND                   
                 sd.BU_ID='PBU' AND
                 shv.DATE_SAMPLE > TO_DATE ('2013-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') 
        GROUP BY      
                 sd.SW_NAME,
                 sd.SAMPLE_NUM,
                 sd.ANALYSIS_RESULT,
                 sd.ANALYSIS_NAME,
                 sd.BU_ID,
                 shv.DATE_SAMPLE
       )
GROUP BY 
         DATE_SAMPLE,
         SW_NAME,
         SAMPLE_NUM,
         BU_ID;
```

Sample of query output (there are several thousand lines similar to this):

```
DATE_SAMPL SW_NAME      SAMPLE_NUM    BU_ID      C1         C2         C3
---------- ------------ ------------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
2013-01-01 02-40        PC66207       PBU        79.981     5.192      1.681
2013-01-01 02-40        PC43602       PBU        79.062     5.333      1.862
2013-01-01 02-40        PC44278       PBU
2013-01-01 02-40        PC61178       PBU
2013-01-01 02-40        PC66207       PBU        79.981     5.192      1.681
2013-01-01 02-40        PC43602       PBU        79.062     5.333      1.862
2013-01-01 02-40        PC44278       PBU
2013-01-01 02-40        PC61178       PBU
2013-01-01 02-40        PC66207       PBU        79.981     5.192      1.681
2013-01-01 02-40        PC43602       PBU        79.062     5.333      1.862
```

A describe on the tables yields:

```
$SQL> DESCRIBE public_project.Sample_Data_Pbu_Lab_Vew

Name                                      Null?    Type
----------------------------------------- -------- -----------------
API                                                VARCHAR2(16)
SW_NAME                                            VARCHAR2(20)
BU_ID                                              VARCHAR2(30)
PROJECT                                            VARCHAR2(30)
SAMPLE_NUM                                NOT NULL VARCHAR2(15)
ANALYSIS_NAME                             NOT NULL VARCHAR2(80)
ANALYSIS_METHOD_NUM                       NOT NULL VARCHAR2(15)
ANALYSIS_RESULT                                    NUMBER
ANALYSIS_UNITS                                     VARCHAR2(20)
ANALYSIS_RESULT_TEXT                               VARCHAR2(80)
DATE_ANALYZED                                      DATE
LAST_UPDATE_ID                                     VARCHAR2(30)
LAST_UPDATE_DATE                                   DATE

SQL> DESCRIBE public_project.Sample_Header_Vew
Name                                      Null?    Type
----------------------------------------- -------- -----------------
API                                                VARCHAR2(16)
SW_NAME                                            VARCHAR2(20)
BU_ID                                              VARCHAR2(30)
PROJECT                                            VARCHAR2(30)
SAMPLE_NUM                                NOT NULL VARCHAR2(15)
COMMENTS                                           VARCHAR2(500)
DATE_SAMPLE                                        DATE
DATE_RECEIVED                                      DATE
METER_NUM                                          VARCHAR2(4)
PWSID                                              NUMBER
SAMPLE_CATEGORY                                    VARCHAR2(20)
SAMPLE_DESC                                        VARCHAR2(80)
SAMPLE_FACILITY                                    VARCHAR2(18)
SAMPLE_LAB                                         VARCHAR2(15)
SAMPLE_POINT                                       VARCHAR2(80)
SAMPLE_TYPE                                        VARCHAR2(20)
LAST_UPDATE_ID                                     VARCHAR2(30)
LAST_UPDATE_DATE                                   DATE
SAMPLE_DEPTH                                       NUMBER
SAMPLE_DEPTH_REF                                   VARCHAR2(5)
```

Comment: Post the definitions of the two tables, `INSERT` statements to load some sample data, and tell us what output you expect.

Comment: What determines a duplicate? You haven't told us... can you as Justin asks provide sample input that accurately demonstrates your problem and a description of what you're trying to do, i.e. what data you're trying to return and why.

Comment: Do at least some of your `date_sample` values have a time component? It looks like you might have the data duplicated in your table but with different times, though it's rather hard to tell from just the results, and that might just be from the cross join between the two tables. Running your query but with a `to_char(date_sample, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'` (or an `alter session`) might be helpful, at least to rule that out.

Comment: What is the relationship between `Sample_Data_Pbu_Lab_Vew` and `Sample_Header_Vew`?  In the query above there are no JOINs and nothing in the WHERE clause which ties the two together so it's giving you all rows from the first table joined to each and every row in the second.  Based on the table definitions it looks like they should be joined using API, SW_NAME, BU_ID, PROJECT, and SAMPLE_NUM as these are common to both tables.

Comment: Thank you all for your assistance. I'm new to data mining and don't have much support. I finally figured this out. @AlexPoole you were right: doing a trunc on the dates cut out a lot of the duplication.

Comment: @BobJarvis, there was some sort of problem - I could not join the tables on API, SW_NAME, PROJECT OR SAMPLE_NUM. I managed to tie them together using the BU_ID in the WHERE clause. Thank you all for your help - your advice made my life a lot easier.